# Return ViewModel from radio button when submit in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have returned model to view with object variant details. Each object can have more than one variant.

```
@model ViewModels.ObjectDetailViewModel

<div>
@Model.ObjectDescription
@Model.ObjectPrice
</div>
```

As you can see in my view I use details from chosen variant. But in the same page I have also radio buttons for changing variant. So I store my variants in TempData and I show them in radio buttons like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToBasket", "Basket", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Choose size:
    @foreach (var objecct in TempData.Peek("Variants") as IList<ViewModels.ObjectDetailViewModel>)
    {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => Model.VariantID, @objecct .VariantID, options) @objecct .VariantName (@CurrencyHelper.FormatCurrency(object.Price.ToString()))
    }
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Add to basket" style="margin-top:10px;" />

}
```

In that approach in Basket controller I have returned my ObjectDetailViewModel, but only VariantId is set (because I connect radio button for this field).

How can I get model with all set fields like ObjectDescription and ObjectPrice? Should I make some @Html.LabelFor for this fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Html.HiddenFor(...)` to submit those fields without displaying them to the user.

You could also do a server-side lookup to get that information during the submission.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by server-side lookup?

Comment: Use the data you are already submitting (specifically, an ID of some sort) to get that data in your controller rather than having it come from the page.